# Color a longtable

Tags: longtable

When I color the header of a `longtable`, the color extends the table. This does not happen, when I use a normal table. I cannot figure out why this happens, and more important, how to solve it.

A small example of the code is shown, and a picture of the problem.[image]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}

\def\ColorTabelHeader{Gray}

\newcommand*{\BeginHeadcolor}{%
\toprule
\rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
  \noalign{\kern-\belowrulesep \begingroup
  \color{\ColorTabelHeader} \hrule height\belowrulesep
  \endgroup }}
\newcommand*{\EndHeadcolor}{%
  \noalign{\begingroup \color{\ColorTabelHeader}
  \hrule height\aboverulesep \endgroup
  \kern-\aboverulesep } \midrule}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H] 
\caption{A simple table example}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \BeginHeadcolor
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\ 
    \EndHeadcolor
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
   \label{tab:oversigt_Forsogelementer}
  \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{cccc}
\caption{A simple longtable example}\\
\BeginHeadcolor
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\EndHeadcolor
\endfirsthead
\multicolumn{4}{c}%
{\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\
\BeginHeadcolor
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\EndHeadcolor
\endhead
\hline \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
\midrule
\endlastfoot
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: BTW, `longtable` automatically centers the table by default. This is configured by length registers `\LTleft` and `\LTright`. Therefore, environment `center` around `longtable` should be removed.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I did not knew that. Always great to learn some more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\hrule` in the `longtable` goes from the left margin to the right margin,
because it is not set inside the alignment. The `longtable` is processed in chunks to support page breaking.

The package redefines `\hline`, which suffers from the same problem, because it internally also used `\hrule`. The trick, which is used there, is to make a full row across all columns. The number of columns is available in macro `\LT@cols`.

`\LTBeginHeadColor` and `\LTEndHeadColor` for use in `longtable`:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LTBeginHeadcolor}{%
  \toprule
  \multispan\LT@cols
    \vadjust pre{\kern-\belowrulesep}%
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \leaders\hrule height\belowrulesep\hfill
    \endgroup
  \cr
  \rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}%
}
\newcommand*{\LTEndHeadcolor}{%
  \multispan\LT@cols
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \leaders\hrule height\aboverulesep\hfill
    \endgroup
  \cr
  \noalign{%
    \kern-\aboverulesep
  }%
  \midrule
}
\makeatother
```

Full example:

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs} 

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{float}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.95}

\def\ColorTabelHeader{Gray}

\newcommand*{\BeginHeadcolor}{%
  \toprule
  \rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}%
  \noalign{%
    \kern-\belowrulesep
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}\hrule height\belowrulesep
    \endgroup
  }%
}
\newcommand*{\EndHeadcolor}{%
  \noalign{%
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \hrule height\aboverulesep
    \endgroup
    \kern-\aboverulesep
  }%
  \midrule
}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\LTBeginHeadcolor}{%
  \toprule
  \multispan\LT@cols
    \vadjust pre{\kern-\belowrulesep}%
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \leaders\hrule height\belowrulesep\hfill
    \endgroup
  \cr
  \rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}%
}
\newcommand*{\LTEndHeadcolor}{%
  \multispan\LT@cols
    \begingroup
      \color{\ColorTabelHeader}%
      \leaders\hrule height\aboverulesep\hfill
    \endgroup
  \cr
  \noalign{%
    \kern-\aboverulesep
  }%
  \midrule
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[H] 
\caption{A simple table example}
  \begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{cccc}
    \BeginHeadcolor
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
\rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
\textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\ 
    \EndHeadcolor
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular} 
   \label{tab:oversigt_Forsogelementer}
  \end{center}
\end{table}


\begin{longtable}{cccc}
  \caption{A simple longtable example}\\
  \LTBeginHeadcolor
  \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
  \rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
  \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
  \LTEndHeadcolor
\endfirsthead
  \multicolumn{4}{c}%
  {\tablename\ \thetable\ -- \textit{Continued from previous page}} \\[\aboverulesep]
  \LTBeginHeadcolor
  \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
  \rowcolor{\ColorTabelHeader}
  \textbf{First entry} & \textbf{Second entry} & \textbf{Third entry} & \textbf{Fourth entry} \\
  \LTEndHeadcolor
\endhead
  \midrule
  \multicolumn{4}{r}{\textit{Continued on next page}} \\
\endfoot
  \midrule
\endlastfoot
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
  1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\ 1 & 2 & 3  & 4 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page 1]  [image: Page 2]